# jQuery autocomplete ajax TypeError

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

Not sure why I continue to get this error when trying to implement autocomplete with ajax source.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

Here is my route in express.

```
exports.findAllIrds = function(req, res) {
    var name = req.query["value"];
    db.collection('employees', function(err, collection) {
        if (name) {
            collection.find({
                "value": new RegExp(name, "i")
            }, {
                value: 1,
                data: 1,
                _id: 0
            }).toArray(function(err, items) {
                res.jsonp(items);
                //console.log(req.query);
                //console.log(items);
            });
        } else {
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
                res.jsonp(items);
                console.log(req.query);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

If I browse to /receiversjson I get all my json as expected and when I browse /receiversjson?value=293589324 I get

`[{"value": "2935893244","data": "D33HL3RH311911"}]` as expected.

However when I try jquery autocomplete with the following code I get error.

```
$('.item-name textarea').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/receiversjson',
    paramName: 'value',
    autoSelectFirst: true,
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});  



Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

In chrome developer tools network tab I see "receiversjson?value=293589324" and when I click on it it open a page with my json.

```
[{
    "value": "2935893244",
    "data": "D33HL3RH311911"
}]
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Just a guess, but is it not able to find your textarea? You might have a bad jquesry selector?

Comment: I'm no longer in front my my computer to post the HTML. But I believe the selector is right since the error occurs when I type in the textarea.

Comment: Oh, I want sure when the error was happening... I'm not sure you can use autocomplete with a textarea, can you try attaching it to an input of type text or search?

Comment: After reading your comment and doing a google search I think you are right about my problem  being with a textarea. I will give your suggestion a go and will follow up with my findings. Thanks

Comment: I was able to get autocomplete working on a textarea... I did see the following documentation that suggests using the option "dataType: jsonp" if you're using json. https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Comment: my datatype is jsonp "res.jsonp(item);" and I'm getting the same error with an input.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was the json respond wasn't including "suggestions:" my output was this

```
[
  {
    "value": "1999458647",
    "data": "A10GA8CW330293"
  }
]
```

JQuery Autocomplete was looking for this.

```
{
  "suggestions": [
    {
      "value": "1999458647",
      "data": "A10GA8CW330293"
    }
  ]
}
```

I currently got it working with this.

```
exports.findAllIrds = function(req, res) {
    var name = req.query["value"];
    db.collection('employees', function(err, collection) {
        if (name) {
            collection.find({"value": new RegExp(name, "i")},{value:1,data:1,_id:0}).toArray(function(err, items) {
                var myobj = {};
                var suggestions = 'suggestions';
                myobj[suggestions] = items;
                res.jsonp(myobj);
            });
        } else {
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
                res.jsonp(items);
                console.log(req.query);
            });
        }
    });
};
```